# Encoding - What is this function?

Tags: encoding

I'm porting and updating an old app and I came across this function. I'd like to know more about it, but I don't actually know what it's called. I'm assuming it has a popular name. Does anyone know?

This version is in Python, although it was originally in Java.

```
def encode(msg): # msg is a string

  msg_len = len(msg)
  j = (msg_len + 6) / 7
  k = 0

  cbytesOutput = [ctypes.c_byte(0)]*(msg_len + j) # return is msg length + j bytes long

  for l in xrange(j):
    i1 = l * 8
    j1 = i1
    byte0 = ctypes.c_byte(-128)
    byte1 = ctypes.c_byte(1)
    k1 = 0
    while k1 < 7 and k < msg_len:
        byte2 = ctypes.c_byte(ord(msg[k]))
        if (byte2.value & 0xffffff80) != 0:
            byte0 = ctypes.c_byte(byte0.value | byte1.value)
        j1 += 1
        cbytesOutput[j1] = ctypes.c_byte(byte2.value | 0xffffff80)
        byte1 = ctypes.c_byte(byte1.value << 1)
        k += 1
        k1 += 1

    cbytesOutput[i1] = byte0

  return cbytesOutput
```

Any comments on the algorithm in general? I'm thinking of replacing it. Profiler says it's the worst function in the entire app (it's 60% of the time on the slowest code path) and it bloats the data as well.

Thanks

Comment: Could it be the base64 encoding? Any example input-output pairs?

Comment: Looks like a SMTP-friendly encoding that encodes each symbol in 7 bits. Might be UTF-7, but I cannot guarantee.